# Node reply with NaN, whenever I pass any variable, that hold String Value to console.log()?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Like, given below is code, which serve a from to user. But when submit data to the form, on the console it says, 'NaN'

```
var server = require('http').createServer();
var fs = require('fs');
var util = require('util');
server.on('request', function(req,res){
    switch(req.method){
        case 'POST':
            var body ='';
            req.on('data',function(data){
                body=+data;
            });
            req.on('end',function(){
                console.log(body);
            });
            break;

        case 'GET':
            console.log('GET request');
            res.statusCode = 200;
            res.setHeader('Content-Type' , 'text/html');
            res.end('<html><body><form action="/" method="POST"><input type="text" name="username"><input type="submit" value="submit"></form></body></
    }

}).listen(4000);
```

Comment: It's `+=`, not `=+`.

Comment: `=+` will try to convert data to an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `body=+data;` with `body+=data;`

Comment: oh yes .... Thanks ..that was a code error ....wrote wrong code
But why it didnt threw an error

Comment: Because it tries to do a type conversion